# JS переменная выводит только последний элемент PHP

Tags: javascript, php, битрикс

JS переменная выдаёт только последний элемент PHP.

```
<script>
    ymaps.ready(init);
     
    function init () {
        var mapix = [<?php echo $coord;?>];
        alert('ТЕСТ: ' + mapix);
```

Вывод просто в php даёт результат:

```
[55.773034,55.773034],[55.743776,37.678128],[55.550071,37.710755],[55.763775,37.526462],
```

А вывод в JS:

```
alert('ТЕСТ: ' + mapix);
ТЕСТ: 55.763775,37.526462
```

Тобишь даёт последнее значение. Что может быть не так и как побороть?

Comment: Думаю у вас где-то в php есть цикл coord по coords

Comment: @AzizUmarov
``$coords = $res57['ADRESS_KOORD']['VALUE'];
$coord = '['.$coords.']';``

Всё что есть...
Но ведь в echo всё хорошо...

Comment: Так вот передайте coords

Comment: @AzizUmarov ``var mapix = [<?php echo $coords;?>];
        alert(mapix);`` - получаю то же самое ``55.763775,37.526462``

Comment: var mapix = <?php echo  json_encode($coords);?>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885737/pass-a-php-array-to-a-javascript-function

Comment: @AzizUmarov Да, видел тему, но пока ничего не помогло. Даже json :/

Comment: Сделайте echo в любой тег посмотрите что там сгенерировано

Comment: @AzizUmarov Вытащил с цикла получение, отображает и в echo одну координату. Как теперь можно реализовать все координаты без того цикла? :)

Comment: Говорил же что у вас цикл. Подкиньте побольше кода вашего php

Comment: @AzizUmarov ``<? 
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>$IBLOCK, "IBLOCK_SECTION_ID"=>$arResult['PROPERTIES']['FILIALY']['VALUE'],"ACTIVE"=>"Y");
$arGroupBy = Array("NAME", "ADRESS_KOORD");
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array("NAME"=>"ASC", "ADRESS_KOORD"), $arFilter, $arGroupBy);
while($arFields = $res->GetNext()) {
 $idx = $arFields['ID'];
}
?>``

Не голый php(bitrix), цикл видно)

Comment: @AzizUmarov ``$res55 = CIBlockElement::GetByID($idx);
$res56 = $res55->GetNextElement(); 
$res57 = $res56->GetProperties(); 
$res58 = $res56->GetFields();
$coords = $res57['ADRESS_KOORD']['VALUE'];
$coord = '['.$coords.'],';
echo $coords;`` То что вытащилось с цикла

Comment: Поправьте и добавьте в вопрос пожалуйста